# Exception in thread "main" - Smartface

Tags: smartface.io

I'm trying to create plugin in smartface spp studio.APK builded successfully in android studio  But in smarface command line interface appears error:Exception in thread "main"

Comment: How did you try it on command line?

Comment: Just i have another issue.    
when i use "npm install smartface -g" command  and then “smfc -i” throws error : "Cannot find module '. . /node_modules/jsdoc/node_modules/wrench' "   what i swrong?

Comment: you should run smfc -i under ".\node_modules\.bin"

Comment: Thanks but i have same error http://i.imgur.com/MkZhZBw.png

Comment: Your reply is useful for me.thanks.I have run smfc -i under ".\node_modules\.bin" after npm install. I'm just trying to create Hello World plugin https://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/plugins/hello-world-with-android-plugin/.at the last step  doas't generates zip file. creates only .temp folder.Can you give me any advice?